# Как запретить копировать определенный файл? C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Написал такой код, суть в том что в файле Info.txt лежит три значения. Адрес куда нужно копировать, что нужно копировать и что не нужно копировать. С помощью библиотеки filesystem я копирую данные и выполняю первый пункт из Info, говоря куда нужно скопировать

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    string path = "Info.txt";
    int i = 0;
    string info[3];
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"open" << endl;
       string ch;  
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            ch = "";
            getline(fin,ch); 
            info[i] = ch;
            cout << info[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    fs::remove_all(L"C:\\Users\\apash\\Desktop\\diplom\\bd\\");
    fs::path sourceFile;
    sourceFile = (L"C:\\Users\\apash\\Desktop\\diplom\\prog\\");
    fs::path targetParent;
    targetParent = info[1];
      fs::create_directories(targetParent); 
      fs::copy(sourceFile, targetParent);
```

Но я не могу придумать решение для оставшихся задач. Как запретить копировать файлы  с именем например "pa.*"

Comment: Запретить **как**? На уровне программы? Просто не копируйте :) На уровне системном? А какая ОС?

Comment: на уровне программы) все верно. Я просто не до конца понимаю как это сделать. Изначально я копирую все и мне нужно, чтобы вот конкретный файл с названием не копировался. Извините за глупые вопросы конечно

Comment: Делайте копирование не одним вызовом `fs::copy()` на все файлы, а перебирайте файлы по одному и копируйте по одному, предварительно проверяя на условие `не копировать`.

Comment: получается мне нужно сделать какой-то список со всеми именами файлов и их местонахождением и в цикле сравнивать подходит ли условие и если подходит не копировать этот файл, правильно я понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скопировать файл, должны быть права на его чтение. Пользуясь этим знанием, убираем лишние права:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
const fs::path path{"/path/to/the/file"};
// Equivalent to 'chmod 700 <file>'
fs::status(path).permissions(fs::perms::owner_all);
// Equivalent to 'chmod 000 <file>'
fs::status(path).permissions(fs::perms::none);
```

И ещё совет, используйте *raw string literal*:

```cpp
RL"C:\path\to\the\file"
```

**PS:** Тогда попробуйте так:

```cpp
fs::permissions(path,fs::perms::none,fs::perm_options::replace);
```

Comment: Вроде бы делаю как вы указали. Ставлю perms::none на путь к файлу который не нужно копировать, но программа все равно выполняет копирование. Что-то делаю не так? Прошу прощение, если я задаю глупый вопрос

Comment: @ArturPi, поправил, попробуйте. Я сам никогда не пользовался, так что...

Comment: @ArturPi, а ещё убедитесь, что приложение запущено не от имени owner'а, если вы отправляете `fs::perms::owner_all`

Comment: Все равно копирует( Попробую и дальше экспериментировать с правами. Вам спасибо большое